# Can I edit files on a bootable USB?

Tags: iso-image, bootable-media

I have a bootable USB stick that I originally created from an ISO file.
If I now edit a file on this USB stick, will it still boot and work properly?

The ISO installs a modified version of CentOS and I made the USB bootable with [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io).

Comment: Depends on what  and how you edit.

Comment: What do you want to edit?

Comment: How exactly did you transfer the image to the USB drive? What filesystem is it now? What operating system are you going to edit files on?

Comment: The ISO is just a disk image that simplifies getting everything onto the drive, with certain files in the right physical location, if necessary.  It's like loading software from an installation disk.  Once you've written the ISO to the drive, the drive contents are the individual files.  How the files got there is no longer relevant.

Comment: @fixer1234 That’s not entirely true. A ISO-Hybrid image can be applied directly (with `dd`, for example) but cannot be modified because it is a read-only filesystem. (IIRC)

Comment: @DanielB, my understanding was that an ISO-Hybrid could be installed on multiple types of media, but once installed, is no longer an ISO.  It can be mounted while still an ISO (in that usage, you can't edit component files, at least in the normal way).  If the USB stick is directly bootable, doesn't that imply that it's no longer an ISO (i.e., not any type of ISO file just being stored on the stick and mounted)?

Comment: @fixer1234 Except it isn’t “installed”. It is copied, bit by bit. That means there’s no change in the data structure. This is different from earlier bootable USB drives where the files were “extracted” and ISOLINUX was replaced with SYSLINUX. [See here](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid).

Comment: @DanielB, interesting, but that description isn't imparting the same understanding for me as you describe.  Isn't copying with dd essentially the same as burning to an optical disk, only it allows you to do it to a flash drive?  When you're done with that process, doesn't the flash drive contain the component files rather than the single ISO file?  If you clone a disk image, you get a single image file.  If you dd that onto another drive, you get a clone of the original drive rather than a copy of the image file.  A copy command, rather than dd, would be needed to preserve the ISO as an ISO.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes that’s how it works. However, ISO is a read-only filesystem, even on a read-write medium. It may not be a file container anymore, but it’s still ISO. Why not just try it yourself, e.g. with Debian’s netinst image. It’s UEFI-bootable, so you’ll see something slightly different, but it’ll convey the idea.

Comment: @DanielB, I don't have a spare flash drive on-hand that's big enough, but I expect that some of the Linux distros I've burned before were ISO-Hybrids, so I'm not connecting with your point and not sure what I would be looking for that's different.  If the ISO is no longer in the file container, it's no longer an ISO.  Are you saying that creating a flash drive from an ISO-Hybrid leaves the entire result with different permission restrictions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41469/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-fixer1234).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I made a bootable USB stick from an ISO file. If I edit a file on this
>   USB stick, will it still boot and work properly?

A bootable USB flash drive is no different than any bootable device. If I edit files in my documents directory on a USB flash drive it’s no different than editing files on a hard drive.

Heck, I can edit the contents of an application on my hard drive I can still boot my hard drive… The application might be hosed, but my overall system works. But if I edited a system file I *might* cause a problem that could cause the system to fail if I edited the file in a way that… Just puts the system at risk.

But this is all dependent on what file you have edited and where you did it and how you did it and is not unique to you creating a bootable USB flash drive from an ISO or otherwise.

Comment: this is wrong.  These iso's of OS's have checksums.  Under no circumstances can you edit naively and have the thing still work.

Comment: what on earth does "edit the contents of an application" mean?(that is such an untechnical term)

Answer (score 9):

You clarified your question with the fact that you used [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to make the flash drive bootable.  For your situation, the accepted answer is correct.  However, the answer could be different for some other readers depending on how they prepared their flash drive.  A more general answer:

**ISO 9660 Filesystem**

An ISO is not simply a file wrapper containing a disk image.  The ISO 9660 standard involves a filesystem that was designed for read-only optical media.  If you write the image to a CD or DVD, it is being used "as designed".  If you write it to a flash drive, however, it gets a little more complicated, and how you write it can make a difference.

**ISO vs. ISO-Hybrid**

The BIOS doesn't require a master boot record (MBR) to boot from an optical disk, so a standard ISO doesn't contain one.  If you write the ISO to a flash drive, you need an additional tool, like UNetbootin, to add the MBR to make the drive bootable (or to modify it to boot a UEFI system without turning off Secure Boot, which at least [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) can do).

An ISO-Hybrid includes a MBR, so you can write it to a flash drive and not need an additional tool to make it bootable.

**Writing Methods**

Flash drives are typically pre-formatted FAT32.  If you are going to install Linux, you will probably format it to one of the ext formats.  There are two approaches to getting the ISO onto the flash drive.  One extracts the ISO contents and writes them onto the existing filesystem.  That retains the read-write capability.  Once the installation is complete, you can edit the contents.

Alternatively, you can do a byte-for-byte write using a command like `dd` in Linux.  That transfers the ISO 9660 filesystem, as well as the component files in the image, so the result is read-only.

**Implication**

If you created the bootable flash drive in the "traditional" way, retaining the drive's filesystem and making it bootable with an additional tool, the drive will be writable.  So to your question, "**If I edit a file on this USB stick, will it still boot and work properly?**", the answer is yes (as long as what you edit isn't a critical system file that your edit corrupts).

If you created the bootable flash drive by using `dd` to write an ISO-Hybrid, the answer is that you won't be capable of editing files on the drive.

Comment: My discussion with Daniel B, which was moved from comments on the question to chat, will not be retained permanently, so I'm sharing the gist here.